# What does except method in rails do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in a Controller. It's very difficult to make sense out of it.

```
allow user: :is_admin?, :except => [:new, :create]
```

It's very difficult to make sense what except method is doing in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:expect` in the above line indicates that the user is allowed `if_admin?` returns true for all actions **EXCEPT** :new and :create. Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think it answers my question, I was asking that If user is a admin the will he get access to new and create.

Answer (score 1):

`:except` is not a method, it's a symbol which used as the hash key.

And you code messed up with two hash styles, the method is `allow`,

the parameter is a hash `{:user => :is_admin?, :except => [:new, :create]}`,

Comment: It could also be a single hash rt? Im jus curious.. :)

Comment: @santhosh Sorry, it's a single hash.

Answer (score 0):

Please see documentation for allow method for the right explanation.
But my assumption is

- Allow admin to do all actions
- Allow users to do all actions except :new and :create

Answer (score 0):

`:except` specifies that the `:new` and `:create` actions in the controller cannot be accessed. However, `is_admin?` is a boolean that evaluates to true if the condition is true. Therefore, If the user is an admin he will **not** have access to :new and :create, but will have access to all other actions in the controller. This is what you are asking I believe according to your comment.

You could allow the user if he is an admin to access the :new and :create actions by the inverse of `:except`, by changing `:except` to `:only`